# what does rich:isUserInRole call?

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using RichFaces 3.3.3 with JSF 1.2 and I would like to understand the behaviour behind rich:isUserInRole. What is being called? When and where it is fired in server side?

For reference: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Functions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Functions-richisUserInRole

Comment: Looks like the component is for RF 4 (the link points to RF 4.2). The RF documentation about the js function gives all the info you need, for more info read [HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String)) as EJP states in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns, or should return, the result of `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole().`

Comment: It also appears at this stage to be completely broken in RichFaces 4.5.7 with EL 2.2, Mojarra 2.2.08, Server 3.0.